# How to trigger email-notification after every build with attaching a html file in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I am new to Jenkins and i have configured email trigger but not understanding how to provide the path of the url to export the html file with the email trigger.

Below is the url of the html file
http://x.x.x.x:8080/view/WSM/job/WSM_Systemtest/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/logs/WSM_Systemtest_Build_231/testmap/231_WSM_Systemtest_testmap.html

Note: url changes after every build as the build name and number will change.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the file to the workspace and then you can put the filename in the attachments field in the job config